# cannot convert ‘tf2_ros::TransformListener*’ to ‘tf2_ros::Buffer*’

Tags: ros, navigation, tf2, base-local-planner, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to upgrade some existing code that use tf with kinetic to use instead tf2 with noetic.

In the following line of code, `planner_` is of type [base_local_planner::TrajectoryPlannerROS](https://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/base_local_planner/html/classbase__local__planner_1_1TrajectoryPlannerROS.html) and the code wants to call its [initialize](https://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/base_local_planner/html/classbase__local__planner_1_1TrajectoryPlannerROS.html#a9a758c9bd9cb0202ed06c07c5aa49c03) function.

```
planner_.initialize("TrajectoryPlannerROS", &tf_, &costmap_ros_);
```

The function signature for "initialize" is:

```
void base_local_planner::TrajectoryPlannerROS::initialize   (   
  std::string   name,
  tf2_ros::Buffer *     tf,
  costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS *    costmap_ros 
}
```

and the documentation says that `tf` is "a pointer to a **transform listener**", despite its type being [tf2_ros::Buffer](https://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/tf2_ros/html/c++/classtf2__ros_1_1Buffer.html).

In the line of code above, `tf_` is of type [tf2_ros::TransformListener](https://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/tf2_ros/html/c++/classtf2__ros_1_1TransformListener.html), which seems to match the documentation. However, the compiler throws an error that:

**error: cannot convert ‘tf2_ros::TransformListener*’ to ‘tf2_ros::Buffer*’**

I am very confused. How should one pass in a tf2_ros::TransformListener as a parameter of type tf2_ros::Buffer? The documentation is very confusing.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/393967/cannot-convert-%E2%80%98tf2_ros::transformlistener*%E2%80%99-to-%E2%80%98tf2_ros::buffer*%E2%80%99/) by [zkytony](https://answers.ros.org/users/26716/zkytony/) on ROS Answers with karma: 178 on 2022-01-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems like they forgot to update the documentation when [porting from tf to tf2_ros](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/commit/a2837b5a9dc6dd4b4da176fca7d899d6a3722bf8), and hence the confusing docs.

You should trust the function signature, `tf2_ros::Buffer *tf` over the documentation.
You cannot convert a `tf2_ros::TransformListener` to a `tf2_ros::Buffer`.

A reference to an existing `tf2_ros::Buffer` is passed as an argument to the constructor of [tf2_ros::TransformListener](https://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/tf2_ros/html/c++/classtf2__ros_1_1TransformListener.html). That same `tf2_ros::Buffer` is what you have to pass to `base_local_planner::TrajectoryPlannerROS::initialize()` as an argument.

There seems to be no way of obtaining a reference to the buffer from the transformListener.

So, if you've constructed `tf_` locally, then you'll have access to the buffer that you used in constructing it already. If you've passed `tf_` in as a reference, consider passing the buffer in as a reference and use it to call `initialize`.

---

Originally posted by [ijnek](https://answers.ros.org/users/73298/ijnek/) with karma: 460 on 2022-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ijnek](https://answers.ros.org/users/73298/ijnek/) on 2022-02-01**:
@zkytony If this answered your question correctly, would you be able to mark as correct and close-off the question? Thanks!